# Parse text file into SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I transform the following block of text which is excerpt from one application log in txt format:

```
ID: 1
Name: John

ID: 2
Name: Doe
```

into the following format:

```
ID Name 
1  John
2  Doe
```

Comment: Basically first format is excerpt from one application log in txt format, and second format which I am looking for, probably may be achieved by transposing and pivoting initial format in excel, or by implementing some sql query after I import it into sql server. But, I didn't try neither of them because I am not sure what approach is most elegant.

Comment: Why not start by using a language you know post back if you have specific problems. Non-specific questions tend to get closed quickly...

Comment: You are right, although this is my first appearance here, I'll try to stick to the rules on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to read the log file, parse it, and output to the new format.

You can use `Loop, Parse` to read the contents based on the colon `:` delimeter. It's quite neat!